# Bash scripting - execute and grep command inside script

Tags: bash

Okay, so I'm learning Bash, and there's that exercise;

*"Write a script that checks every ten seconds if the user 'user000' is logged in."*

My idea is to `grep` a `who`, but I don't know how to incorporate this into a script. I tried things like

```
if [ `who | grep "user000"` ] then things
```

but it returns the matched lines with grep, not true/false.

Answer (score 7):

You want `grep -q`.  That's "quiet mode"; just sets status based on whether there were any matches, doesn't output anything.  So:

```
if who | grep -q "user000"; then things; fi
```

Comment: FYI - Solaris's `grep` does not support `-q`

Comment: DVK: Too bad. POSIX grep specifies `-q' since 1997: http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7990989775/xcu/grep.html

Also, drop the brackets. It's the shell equivalent of if (var == true) {}

Comment: Probably want to throw a "|cut -d1 -b' '" in there and use "grep '^user000$'".  This will avoid false positives when 'user0001' logs in.

Comment: Well, I meant drop the brackets and the backticks. The shell will evaluate the exit value of the command transparently.

Comment: And then you want to add a ';' before the 'then' or start it on a new line. OR, you can do it in an && list:

`who | grep -q "user000" && things`.

(Sorry. I would have just edited your answer if I had the ability)

Comment: guns - you know, some people actually care about portability. And some people are not into righteousness of using One True XXX (in this case XXX=variant of Unix)

Comment: @DVK: What's not portable about my suggestions? It's classic sh as far as I know. I agree with you about not using `grep -q`, if that's what you're referring to.

Comment: @DVK: Oh I see. I didn't mean "screw solaris", but "that's unfortunate".

Answer (score 3):

You can do

```
who | grep "user000" > /dev/null  2>&1
# You can use "-q" option of grep instead of redirecting to /dev/null 
# if your grep support it. Mine does not.
if [ "$?" -eq "0" ]
then ...
```

This uses $? - a Shell variable which stores the return/exit code of the last command that was exected. `grep` exits with return code "0" on success and non-zero on failure (e.g. no lines found returns "1" ) - a typical arrangement for a Unix command, by the way.

Comment: Your redirection `>&!` creates a file called "!". Perhaps you mean `... 2>&1 > /dev/null`

Comment: That's cause I used csh refirection instead of sh redirection by force of habit - didn't do anything in bourne in ages :)

Answer (score 2):

If you're testing the exit code of a pipe or command in a `if` or `while`, you can leave off the square brackets and backticks (you should use `$()` instead of backticks anyway):

```
if who | grep "user000" > /dev/null 2>&1
then
  things-to-do
fi
```

Comment: You can also leave off the quotes around user000.

Answer (score 1):

Most answers have the right idea, but really you want to drop all output from grep, including errors.  Also, a semicolon is required after the ] for an if:

```
if who | grep 'user000' >/dev/null 2>&1; then
    do things
fi
```

If you are using GNU grep, you can use the `-s` and `-q` options instead:

```
if who | grep -sq 'user000'; then
    do things
fi
```

EDIT: dropped brackets; if only needs brackets for comparison ops

Comment: You can duplicate file descriptors and shorten the redirection spec.

Comment: Semicolon is only required when _then_ appears on the same line. When _then_ is on the following line, it is not needed.

Comment: Why do you do the redirection in two times instead of using &>, is there a reason ? (pure curiosity).

Answer (score 0):

It's probably not the most elegant incantation, but I tend to use:

```
if [ `who | grep "user000" | wc -l` = "1" ]; then ....
```

Comment: why not use 'who | grep -c user000' ?

Comment: What if the user is logged in more than once?

Comment: @Manni: hadn't thought of the -c flag to grep. Is that Posix though, or an extension?

@Dennis: does `who` list one mention per login shell?

Comment: I'm ssh'd into a server a couple of time, plus a couple of xterms, plus the gdm login or whatever so my name appears five times in who right now.

Comment: @the_mandrill: since -c also works on ancient solaris boxes, I guess it's Posix.